# Amazon ELB or Apache2 with mod_jk or mod_ajp With Glassfish Cluster

Tags: session, glassfish, apache2, cluster-computing, load-balancing

I'm having some issues with session replication while using Amazon ELB (elastic load balancer).

Most of the documentation and online questions and blogs talk about using Apache2 as a load balancer for Glassfish clusters. Is there an added benefit to using Apache versus ELB. Does it aid when session failover is needed?

I'm trying to see if using ELB is part of the problem I'm having with the present configuration.